# Reading API keys with ConfigParser

Tags: python, configparser

I am trying to read API keys with ConfigParser but I get a traceback:

```
 NoSectionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-c861940d7d10> in <module>
      5 configFilePath = r'c:\twitter.cfg'
      6 config.read(configFilePath)
----> 7 APP_KEY = config.get('credentials','app_key')
      8 APP_SECRET = config['credentials']['app_secret']
      9 twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, oauth_version=2)

~\Anaconda3\lib\configparser.py in get(self, section, option, raw, vars, fallback)
    778         """
    779         try:
--> 780             d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
    781         except NoSectionError:
    782             if fallback is _UNSET:

~\Anaconda3\lib\configparser.py in _unify_values(self, section, vars)
   1144         except KeyError:
   1145             if section != self.default_section:
-> 1146                 raise NoSectionError(section) from None
   1147         # Update with the entry specific variables
   1148         vardict = {}

NoSectionError: No section: 'credentials'
```

my code is as follows:

```
config = ConfigParser()
configFilePath = r'c:\twitter.cfg'
config.read(configFilePath)
APP_KEY  = config.get('credentials','app_key')
APP_SECRET  = config['credentials']['app_secret']
```

my twitter.cfg file:

```
[credentials]
app_key = aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
app_secret = aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: could you paste the full error traceback ?

Comment: @MiguelTrejo the post has been updated with the full traceback.

Comment: There is a small problem with `configparser` that if the file doesn't exist, you don't get a matching error. For example, even if you did `config.read(r'imaginary path')` you would still get the `No section: 'credentials'` error. My point is: Make sure the file exists and that the path is correct. Try to open it regularly, using `open` and make sure it works. Try a capital `C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that the file is not found by python, so you would need to take a look at the path to the file and make sure it's correct.

The `read()` method of `configparser` is designed so that any non-existing file is silently ignored (meaning the FileNotFoundError is caught and suppressed). This is because it should be possible to input a list of possible configuration files from which you get a list of successfully read configuration files as a response. In this scenario you wouldn't want your program to crash in case only a subset of the possible configuration files exist.

**A simple solution** for you would be to place the configfile in the same dir as you stand in when you call your python program, and only look for `configparser.read("twitter.cfg")`

**If you want a FileNotFoundError to be thrown**, consider using `configparser.read_file()` instead, which takes a file object as parameter. In this case we would get a FileNotFoundError thrown in case it's not found by Python.

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
configFilePath = 'twitter.cfg'
with open(configFilePath) as f:
    config.read_file(f)
APP_KEY = config.get('credentials', 'app_key')
APP_SECRET = config['credentials']['app_secret']
print(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
```

Answer (score 2):

from doc

> If none of the named files exist, the ConfigParser instance will
> contain an empty dataset

make sur your path and your file exist try this  :

```
config = ConfigParser()
configFilePath = r'c:\twitter.cfg'
data=config.read(configFilePath)
if len(data) == 0:
    raise ValueError("Failed to open/find config file")
APP_KEY  = config.get('credentials','app_key')
APP_SECRET  = config['credentials']['app_secret']
```